# configure jetty to download file instead of opening a new tab

Tags: java, html, webserver, jetty

I'm searching for a solutions / configuration which forces jetty to download linked files instead of opening them in a new tab.

I have a very simple *test.html* containing:

```
<a href="Test.txt" target="_blank">Text</a>
```

If I upload *test.html* and *Test.txt* to my website (running on LiteSpeed V7.9) clicking the link downloads the *Test.txt*.

If I add *test.html* and *Test.txt* to the ROOT webapp of a complete fresh jetty setup ([downloaded current version 10.0.6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-home/10.0.6/jetty-home-10.0.6.zip)) and click the link from http://localhost:8080/test.html the file opens a new tab.

So I'm hoping there must be some configuration to define the behavior but haven't found one looking in the *jetty.xml*.

EDIT: I downloaded a tomcat 9.0.52 and tested the behavior, it is the same as with jetty. Considering that other common webservers use the same handling I think it would be bad to change global configuration. According to the comments it would make more sense to use e.g. the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute for links.

Comment: You could add a download attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download (the difference is in what headers are sent to the browser -- have a look at the two responses and see what's different)

Comment: Do you ever want `Test.txt` (or any other `*.txt` file on your server) to be displayed to the browser?  A server based configuration is an all or nothing approach, you either change that behavior for all files ending with the same extension, or not.   Can you separate "files for download" and "files for display" in some fashion (by context path, or extension?)